# multiple hierarchy in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design, database-schema

I do have a problem where I am having a hard time figuring out how to lay out the relationship in coredata. I tried to visualize the problem below.

Basically in my application users have STATEMENTS that are made of TERMS.

- One or more TERMS make STATEMENTS[1].
- Users can also tap on a term[2] and
- create another statement that's connected to this term[3].
- Once they solve this sub statement[4]
- they can go back to the main statement [5] and highlight another term and so on.

They should be able to go deeper than one level if need be. Say, select another term in sub statement and create another statement etc.
I am not sure how to create such a schema in coredata.

I already have my TERM and STATEMENT entities, and I initially separated STATEMENT AND SUBSTATEMENT as two different entities but I am not entirely sure if this is a approach anymore.

I think a more efficient approach would be to store each statement in just one entity and have a relationship with TERM but I Am not sure how to figure out the levels.

I would appreciate any directions.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you just have one entity (let's call it a term) which has a value and one or more sub terms (which are references to the same entity type).the entity should also have a reference to its parent term entity What you call a statement is just the special case of a term entity with no parent value

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the answer. I got that I should store a reference to the parent entity in the term to access it later. However, I don't understand why I should have just one entity. In my current setup I am using TERMS to make STATEMENTs. So each term already holds a reference to the statement it's part of. What you suggest is, it should also have an attribute to hold a reference for a parent statement which is optional. Did I get this right? I don't get why I shouldn't need a statement entity. Thanks again.

Comment: Because from what I can see it is a simple recursive data structure. When you look at the fields/properties that a statement has and that a term has they are the same - the difference is a statement has no parent.